Qemu simulated Raspberry-Pi starts execution at 0x0000 instead of 0x8000 in GDB debugger, Rust bare metal code
I've started the journey towards bare metal embedded programming, and I'm trying to run my "Hello, world!" code example on a emulated raspberry pi 2 with Qemu.
Following different sources of documentation and tutorials, I've managed to compile down my code for armv7a-none-eabi with rust, place the start of my code at address 0x8000 in the .elf file, as I read that raspberries starts their code at this address. My code initialize the UART mini, the GPIO 14 and 15 for the UART mini, and send symbols to the UART mini data register.
As nothing happens, I tried debugging with GDB. However, when connecting to QEMU with GDB, the code pointer is at 0x0000 instead of 0x8000, which makes me think something is really wrong.
I'm starting Qemu like so:
qemu-system-arm -M raspi2b -kernel target/binary/my_custom_code.img -nographic -s -S

Then, I start GDB:
gdb target/armv7a-none-eabi/debug/my_custom_code.elf

I connect to the Qemu process:
(gdb) target remote localhost:1234
Remote debugging using localhost:1234
0x00000000 in ?? ()

After this, nothing happens. any of step, next will throw "Cannot find bounds of current function" error, and continue hangs. I can place breakpoints, but I'm guessing it's because I loaded my file in gdb, not because I'm connected to a properly running program.
Furthermore, when I try to run info reg, I don't get the standard register names for the BCM2837-ARM, which makes me think even more qemu is not running the raspberry or my program properly.
At the end, I'm trying to display text to the console from the raspberry using the mini UART, but as it didn't worked I dived into debugging with GDB, and now it looks like nothing is running properly.
I'm doing all of this on NixOS v24.05.20231209.666fc80, with a shell that uses the packages gcc-arm-embedded, qemu gdb.
Is there something wrong with my raspberry simulation, or my GDB process ? Why isn't the code pointer at 0x8000 ? Did I missed something else regarding connecting the mini UART to the Qemu console ?
I would be happy to provide any more information if needed.

QEMU's raspberry pi model doesn't start binaries in exactly the same way the firmware does on a real hardware pi. You have two choices:
(1) make your binary be one that expects to be started like a Linux kernel, according to the kernel's documented requirements (this includes things like being able to be loaded at an arbitrary address), and pass the binary to the -kernel option as a raw binary, zImage or similar file
(2) make your binary be an ELF file that loads the binary to the right place, and pass the ELF file to either -kernel or to the 'generic loader'. QEMU will honour the ELF entry point for an A-profile Arm ELF file. Note that all the CPUs will start at once and at the same place, and your binary must sort them out and put the secondary CPUs into a holding pen if you don't care about them!
Either way, you'll want to make sure your image includes the code at the reset vector and other interrupt/exception entry points, and has some assembly code to set the CPU up with whatever the requirements Rust has before jumping into non-assembly code (eg it probably expects the FPU to be enabled). You will find it a lot faster if you can find an existing tutorial on how to do this, or at least adapt a known working C example, rather than trying to figure out all the problems by running into them on your own.
For gdb, you need to be using a gdb which understands the Arm architecture. This is often not the standard "gdb" which will be compiled with only host architecture support. You can test this with the gdb command "set arch arm"; if gdb says 'The target architecture is set to "arm"' it has Arm support; if it says 'Undefined item: "arm"' then it does not and you need to use a gdb with the Arm support compiled in. That might be a binary or package named "gdb-multiarch" (which has support for lots of architectures) or it might be a gdb specifically built with cross-gdb arm support in it: you'll need to check how your distro packages that.
